# Code being displayed above question listing

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I visit Academia.SE, there is some code being displayed above the question listing:

> docsHero.RenderPartial(Html); storyHero.RenderPartial(Html);

[image]

macOS 10.12.3, Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Does this problem persist on a reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment on a [main Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293434/254250) bug report, it's been fixed:

> Rolled back to the previous build, then double, triple and quadruple checking the view. Still looking at what happened, but basically, it's a banner that isn't always shown, so I didn't see it and it doesn't always show for everyone. Sorry about that! – Michael Stum♦ 1 hour ago

> Properly fixed it and rolled out the latest build again. – Michael Stum♦ 53 mins ago